# sort array of objects by string property value in JS

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
var masterHeadingObj = {
  'a': "e",
  'b': "d",
  'c': "c",
  'd': "b",
  'e': "a"
};
```

How to sort using the string value

I am expecting this

```
var masterHeadingObj = {
  'e': "a"
  'd': "b",
  'c': "c",
  'b': "d",
  'a': "e",
};
```

Comment: There's no array here, only an object.  Are you asking how to sort the *properties* of an object?  Why do you need to do that?  If the order of values matters, why not use an array instead of an object?